# Can't get value of <select> element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a web app like google sheets in jQuery, but when I try to get a `<select>` value with `$(select).val()` I get `null.

I tried to put the code into `$(button).click()` and then it worked so I think the problem is that Javascript is executed before HTML, but I am not sure.

```
$(function() {
  $.post("getTablesName.php", function(data) {
    $("#tables_SCT").html(data);
  });

  var name = $("#tables_SCT").val();
  $.get("getTable.php", { name: name }, function(data) {
    $("#columns").html(data);
  });
)};
```

I just want to get the `$("#tables_SCT").val()`.

Comment: it looks maybe stupid but what is a AJAX callback? ^^'

Comment: It's the handler function you define in the second argument of `$.post`. It's the logic which will be executed when the data is returned back from the AJAX call you make. For more information, see the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. I've added an answer for you below to make it clearer

Comment: Ok I understand but I want these datas to load instantly after my HTML

Comment: That's not possible when using AJAX. You have to wait for the request to complete. This is why you need to use the callback pattern. If you want to load the data immediately you will need to generate it in PHP and add it to the page when it's initially loaded.

Comment: Ok so I have no other choice to create a button to load my datas for example?

Comment: Not at all. You can make your code work when the page loads, my answer below shows you how to structure it.

Comment: Oh yes I understand!! Thank you very much! It is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the `var name = $("#tables_SCT").val();` line inside the first AJAX callback. As it stands your code is trying to read content which doesn't yet exist in the DOM as the request which fills the option elements is asynchronous.

You will also need to make the second AJAX call from this point too, for the same reason. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $.post("getTablesName.php", function(data) {
    $("#tables_SCT").html(data);

    var name = $("#tables_SCT").val();
    $.get("getTable.php", { name: name }, function(data) {
      $("#columns").html(data);
    });
  });
)};
```